# ScrollViewer scrollbars don't appear when calling ScrollToHorizontalOffset or ScrollToVerticalOffset

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

In Windows Phone `ScrollViewer` scrollbars do not appear when `ScrollToHorizontalOffset` or `ScrollToVerticalOffset` are called.

```
ScrollViewer Name="MyScroll" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
```

The scroll works fine but the scrollbars do not appear.

How do I make these scrollbars to appear?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use a template to get this to work. Take a look at what [Jeff Wilcox did here](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/12/betterscrollviewer/). You should be able to use that or something similar to get the effect you want.